# How do I check if a string is a negative number before passing it through int()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write something that checks if a string is a number or a negative. If it's a number (positive or negative) it will passed through int(). Unfortunately isdigit() won't recognize it as a number when "-" is included.

This is what I have so far:

```
def contestTest():
# Neutral point for struggle/tug of war/contest
x = 0

while -5 < x < 5:
    print "Type desired amount of damage."
    print x
    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if choice.isdigit():
        y = int(choice)
        x += y
    else:
        print "Invalid input."

if -5 >= x:
    print "x is low. Loss."
    print x
elif 5 <= x:
    print "x is high. Win."
    print x
else:
    print "Something went wrong."
    print x
```

The only solution I can think of is some separate, convoluted series of statements that I might squirrel away in a separate function to make it look nicer. I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: what is wrong with:   https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-check-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-python#:~:text=To%20check%20for%20positive%20integers,rest%20must%20represent%20an%20integer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can easily remove the characters from the left first, like so:

```
choice.lstrip('-+').isdigit()
```

However it would probably be better to handle exceptions from invalid input instead:

```
print x
while True:
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        y = int(choice)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input."
x += y
```

Comment: clever solution. thanks.

Comment: maybe it is better: choice.lstrip('-+').isnumeric()

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking if you can convert the input to a number you can just try the conversion and do something else if it fails:

```
choice = raw_input("> ")

try:
    y = int(choice)
    x += y
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid input."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using `float(str)`. float should return an ValueError if it's not a number. If you're only dealing with integers you can use `int(str)`

So instead of doing

```
if choise.isdigit():
   #operation
else:
   #operation
```

You can try

```
try:
    x = float(raw_input)
except ValueError:
    print ("What you entered is not a number")
```

Feel free to replace `float` with `int`, and tell me if it works! I haven't tested it myself.

**EDIT**: I just saw this on Python's documentation as well (2.7.11) [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

isn't this simpler?

```
def is_negative_int(value: str) -> bool:
    """
    ref:
        - https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-check-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-python#:~:text=To%20check%20for%20positive%20integers,rest%20must%20represent%20an%20integer.
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472361/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-negative-number-before-passing-it-through-int
    """
    if value == "":
        return False
    is_positive_integer: bool = value.isdigit()
    if is_positive_integer:
        return True
    else:
        is_negative_integer: bool = value.startswith("-") and value[1:].isdigit()
        is_integer: bool = is_positive_integer or is_negative_integer
        return is_integer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want integers and reject decimal numbers. You can use the following function to check.

```html
def isInteger(string):
  if string[0] == '-': #if a negative number
    return string[1:].isdigit()
  else:
    return string.isdigit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regular expressions to check if the string has the pattern of an integer number before attempting any casting:

```
import re
patternInteger = re.compile("^[+-]?[0-9]+$")

if patternInteger.match(string):
    return int(string)
else:
    return "This string is not an integer number"
```

You can generalize your regex pattern to match other kind of strings that may look like floating point numbers or even complex numbers. In this situation regex might be a bit overkill but can be very useful to learn if in the future you have to deal with a more general pattern to recognise.