# loop until non alphanumeric input

Tags: python, loops

I want this code to be in loop until user enter some input (check for empty string) and print else statement if doesn't match any condition in python

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Here is my code:

```
while True:    
    string_1 = input("enter a  word or number: ")

    if string_1.isalpha():
            print(string_1 ,"is all alphabetical character")
            break

    elif  int(string_1.isdigit()):
        if int(string_1) < 99:
            print(string_1 , "is less than expected")
            break

    if int(string_1) > 99:
            print(string_1 , "is a preety big number") 
            break

    else:
        print(string_1 , "is not alpha nor digit" , "\n")
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: what input you provided, what output you got, what output you expect?

Comment: `int(string_1.isdigit())` isn't doing what you think it is

Comment: In any case, your indentation is off here and the last else is not necessary

Comment: for example i type  "word" it will print  "word is all alphabetical character" if i type a number less than 99 say,44 it will print" 44 is less than expected" if more than 99 say 123 it should print"123 is quite a big number" but if i type anything other than that like"@" or "e123" it should print else statement in end and if i just type it should ask for input again   min value = 99

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that

Answer (score 0):

You need `continue` if you want the loop to repeat. `break` when you want it to end.

Also, I recommend you do input validation first

```
while True:    
    string_1 = input("enter a  word or number: ")

    if not (string_1.isalpha() or string_1.isdigit()):
        print(string_1 , "is not alpha nor digit")
        break

    if string_1.isalpha():
        print(string_1 ,"is all alphabetical character")
        continue

    if string_1.isdigit():
        if int(string_1) < min_value:
            print(string_1 , "is less than expected")
            continue
        elif int(string_1) > min_value:
            print(string_1 , "is a preety big number") 
            continue
        else:  # == min_value
            print("you got it")
```

If you need to handle negative numbers, see

[How do I check if a string is a negative number before passing it through int()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472361/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-negative-number-before-passing-it-through-int)

Comment: Does it need to?

Comment: i want to ask user again for input if  he presses enter key until something is typed what should be added

Comment: Okay... So check for an empty string, and repeat the loop

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the `break` statement from `if` and `elif` conditions.
 Add the break statement in the `else` condition.

```
while True:    
string_1 = input("enter a  word or number: ")

if string_1.isalpha():
        print(string_1 ,"is all alphabetical character")


elif  int(string_1.isdigit()):
    if int(string_1) < min_value:
        print(string_1 , "is less than expected")


    if int(string_1) > min_value:
        print(string_1 , "is a preety big number") 


else:
    print(string_1 , "is not alpha nor digit" , "\n")
    break
```

[Click here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html) to learn about break statement.